# SEO for AC: Revelations

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Should the AC: Revelations tag be [ac-revelations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-revelations) instead of the current [assassins-creed-revel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-revel)?  Google doesn't (predictably) pick up on "revel" = "revelations", but easily seems to equate "ac" with "assassins creed".  The only questions that seem to turn up when Googling are those that actually use the full subtitle "Revelations" in the question title (which is somewhat discouraged) or body.

To clarify: my point is that I don't think an ordinary user is going to use "revel" when searching for these sorts of questions.  Some of the searches ("ac revel") I used were trying to auto-correct "revel" into something else (rebel, reveal).

Comment: Makes sense to me, and the latter can be a synonym to make it more likely to come up when typing in to the tag box for those who start with "assassin"

Comment: Related: Shameless vote canvassing for [Add method to expand tags when used page title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118280/add-method-to-expand-tags-when-used-page-title)

Answer (score 1):

This has long since been done. Community is a dumb user who bumps nonsense and should stop it.